# Unable to highlight text after selenium webdriver click()

Tags: python, angularjs, internet-explorer, silverlight, selenium-webdriver

I am using python code such as below to click an element within an iframe on an angularjs page.

```
browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.switch_to.frame('name')
browser.find_element_by_id('value').click()
```

After using `click()` I am unable to manually highlight text that appears on the page. Why might this happen? How can I restore the ability to highlight text with the mouse?

I have tried switching back to default content, but this makes no difference. Any ideas?

Other strange effects after using `click()`: Links and buttons don't work while using the mouse manually unless double-clicked. These would normally require single click. It is as if there is an invisible overlay blocking text selection or clicking links. Radio buttons and menus still work.

**Edit:** The site uses silverlight and I am wondering if this is related to the problem that results from using `click()`.

Comment: why do you want to highlight text on clicking??

Comment: Not on click. After using click() function I would still like to be able to hilight text manually using the mouse in the webdriver browser.

Comment: you can try : action.moveToElement(toElement);
  action.doubleClick().build().perform();

Comment: Are you suggesting this as an alternative to using the click() function?

Comment: My understanding is you want to highlight a text upon clicking, if yes, then you can highlight using above code on a static text / label as alternate to click()

Comment: No, I want to highlight text by hand after using click() in a python script. The sequence is 1. click() any element 2. Use my hand and mouse to highlight text or click links in other elements as I please.

Comment: Quite strange, I am not able to understand what actually you want to do ??

Comment: The script contains the above code which opens the webdriver browser and sends click() to an element on the page. Now I would like to use my hand to move the mouse arrow over text on the page and hold left-click with my finger to highlight text. It will not allow me to highlight text after click() is used.